# Splitting up a string by regex with multiple capture groups and OR | operators

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
splitRegex = r"(Personal Info|Personal|Personal Information)|(Work Experience|Work)|(Education|School|Certificates)"

text = "Personal Info\nText\nText\nText\nText\nWork Experience\nText\nText\nText\nText\nEducation\nText\nText\nText\nText\nText"

x = [tuple(i.splitlines()) for i in re.split(splitRegex, text) if i != ""]
d = dict([("".join(x[i]), x[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(x) // 2, 2)])
print(d)
```

In the above example code I want to split up the text based on titles. these titles I want to determine by regex (as there can be synonyms) `re.split` however often returns NoneType. This obviously causes errors. If I add an if condition to check if i IS NOT `None`, then the errors disappear but the dictionary will end up missing a lot of data.

Would anyone know of a way to fix this or of a way to achieve the same thing?

Keep in mind that the above is just an example. I need to use this for CV's/Resume's and as such the lay-out and titles can be slightly different depending on which CV is used.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `None` for all the groups that don't match, since `re.split()` includes all capture groups in the resulting list.

You should put each list of alternatives in a non-capturing group, and then put all of them in a single capturing group so you just get the matching label.

```
splitRegex = r"((?:Personal Info|Personal|Personal Information)|(?:Work Experience|Work)|(?:Education|School|Certificates))"
```

Comment: This indeed fixes the whole NoneType error thing which is great! but for some reason I still end up missing data. (for example 67 in dictionary (including titles) vs 80 in total lines)

Comment: I have noticed that if I seperate the re.split call that it does find all the data, so somewhere with the if condition something goes wrong. but I dont understand why..

Comment: If you can make a small example that demonstrates the problem, I can try to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `NoneType`'s in the result at the loop level:

```
    x = [tuple(i.splitlines()) for i in re.split(splitRegex, text) if (i != "" and i != None)]
```

This way `x` will be something like:

```
    [('Personal Info',), ('', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text'), 
    ('Work Experience',), ('', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text'), 
    ('Education',), ('', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Text')]
```

which will probably make your dict constructor happy.

Comment: I had tried this but it seemed to result in the loss of a lot of data. in my example data it seemed like the original had about 115 lines and the dictionary ended up with about 85.

Comment: @SanderBerntsen maybe you could post more data, similar to the data you actually have, specially lines similar to the ones your script is missing.